# Is there a way to split a table in two in lua?

Tags: lua

The goal is to split a lua table into two separated tables.
The expected results are as follows:
local t1 = { value="foo" }
local t2 = { tex="bar" }
From
local t = {
{
value = "foo",
tex = "bar"
}
}

I haven't found a solution for this type of table, as the base table is dynamic and can't be changed.
I have tried iterating the table and inserting only the certain items in a new table. but that failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to split a table in half you can do something like this:

```lua
function SplitInHalf(tbl)
    local t1, t2 = {}, {}  -- create 2 new tables
    local state = true  -- to switch between t1 and t2 we will use a variable
    for k, v in pairs(tbl) do -- iterating original table
        (state and t1 or t2)[k] = v -- depending on the state use t1 or t2 and insert a key in it
        state = not state -- inverse state, if true make false, if false make true 
    end
    return t1, t2 -- return new tables
end
```